# How to add names of list to df as a column to data frame

Tags: r

Is there a better way to add names of list fields (data frames in general) as a column of data frame?

### Example data

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 3:5)
df2 <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 3:5)
df3 <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 3:5)

list = list()
list[["DF1"]] <- df1
list[["DF2"]] <- df2
list[["DF3"]] <- df3
```

It's working, but I want to avoid for loops when possible.

```
 for (i in 1:length(list)) {
     list[[i]][,"name"] <- names(list[i])
    }
```

What I'm trying:

```
lapply(list, FUN = function(df){
  df$anothername <- names(list$df) #This return colnames.
  return(df)
})
```

Output i want to get:

```
$DF1
  x y name
1 1 3  DF1
2 2 4  DF1
3 3 5  DF1

$DF2
  x y name
1 1 3  DF2
2 2 4  DF2
3 3 5  DF2

$DF3
  x y name
1 1 3  DF3
2 2 4  DF3
3 3 5  DF3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `Map` to `cbind` each `data.frame` in the `list` with the corresponding `name` of the `list`.

```
Map(cbind, list, name=names(list))
#$DF1
#  x y name
#1 1 3  DF1
#2 2 4  DF1
#3 3 5  DF1

#$DF2
#  x y name
#1 1 3  DF2
#2 2 4  DF2
#3 3 5  DF2

#$DF3
#  x y name
#1 1 3  DF3
#2 2 4  DF3
#3 3 5  DF3
```

---

A better option would be `rbindlist` to create a single dataset.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list, idcol="name")
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. This is what i wanted to do.

Comment: After edit. I, know, but sometimes is better to hold all dataframes in list, instead of single dataset.

Comment: @M.Siwik  Yes, you are right.  If you need to get some aggregates by group, the `data.table` option would be fast.